# Share Dialog selects Random link

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am using facebook iOS SDK's share dialog:

```
FBLinkShareParams * params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
params.link = url;
NSURL * imageurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: book.FilePath];
params.picture = imageurl;

if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams: params]) {
    // Present share dialog
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink: params.link
    handler: ^ (FBAppCall * call, NSDictionary * results, NSError * error) {
        if (error) {
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
            //NSog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
        } else {
            //NSLog(@"result %@", results);
        }
    }];
}
```

It works properly but problem is it always selects random thumbnail, which is not acceptable by client, so can body tell me how I can select particular image for thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to use the `picture` property of `FBLinkShareParams` to set the url of the desired thumbnail.

You should check the `FilePath` property (why capitalised??) and investigate why you get random results.